# How to log console records for stopped Python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code inside my script to create a log of console records every time the scrip is run:

```
class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pathLogs = 'logs/'
        if not os.path.isdir(pathLogs):
            os.makedirs(pathLogs)
        date_stamp = str(datetime.datetime.now()).split('.')[0]
        date_stamp = date_stamp.replace(" ", "_").replace(":", "")
        file_name = pathLogs + date_stamp + ".log"
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.log = open(file_name, "a")

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        self.log.write(message)
sys.stdout = Logger()
```

It works fine when the script's run finishes by itself, but if you interrupt it, no records that you see in the console get saved in a log file. How can I save records in a log file every time the script is run regardless if it was interrupted or not?

Comment: Python comes with its own [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module that probably does everything you want, and has already solved most of the problems you're likely to run into. If there's a reason you can't use it, that's fine, but if you just didn't know about it, you should consider using it instead.

Comment: Meanwhile, normal file I/O is buffered. You probably want to either disable buffering on your logfile, or explicitly `flush` it after each `write` (either in your `write` method, or via a separate API that your calling code can use). This will, however, slow things down. If that's not acceptable, you need to make sure to do it at shutdown—via a `__del__` method, or an `atexit` function, or  a signal handler. Or you can just add a `close` method and have your top-level code ensure that it gets called—e.g., with a `try:` `finally: logger.close()` around the main program.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the [signal module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html).

Let's say you're interrupting your code by pressing CTRL+C. What you need to do to perform anything after the interuption signal is received is the following:

```
import signal
import sys

def my_callback(signal, frame):

    # Do your stuff...
    print("I have been killed!")
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, my_callback)  # this is your handler
```

Basically, what happens is, as soon as CTRL+C is received (= the `SIGINT` signal), your callback is called and does whatever you want it to do.

For more details, as always, the `signal` [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) is really clear and helpful.
Hope this helps!